# How I can verify that nginx reverse proxy + apache works correctly?

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I've installed nginx reverse proxy + apache2+mod_php.

How I can verify that I've made everything right and nginx works with static content only and apache2 with php only?

Web-application is Magento. So there is only 1 entry-point - index.php and in index.php all statis is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to check the HTTP response headers. They should include the name of the HTTP server software that generated the response in the `Server` header.

Or, even more simply, use `curl`:

```
curl -s -D - "http://<URL of some static content>/" | grep "^Server:"
```

Comment: Note that if the domain ip is behind cloudflare, the server will display as "cloudflare"