# How to test if file is being served by Apache or nginx (nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I have set up nginx as a reverse proxy to Apache, but now would like to test whether it's working. I came across the following answer:

[How I can verify that nginx reverse proxy + apache works correctly?](https://superuser.com/questions/382593/how-i-can-verify-that-nginx-reverse-proxy-apache-works-correctly)

But actually, I get the response "Server: nginx" whether or not I query a file that is served by nginx or Apache. For example, all CGI scripts in my current set up are handled by Apache. However, the response headers for the CGI scripts still say "Server: nginx". The big question for me is determining if static files are being served by nginx, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume they are not served by nginx? Especially since it's configured as a reverse proxy? An easy test would be to turn off nginx and look at the results. You could also let nginx set additional headers or make sure that Apache is only reachable on the localhost interface (which you wouldn't be able to access from the outside).

Comment: Yes, I would've thought that nginx would've been serving the static files, except for certain problems I noticed that lead me to believe they were, in fact, being handled by Apache. And I was right!

I ultimately tracked this down by having Apache use mod_headers to add an "X-Powered-By: Apache" header.

Comment: You didn't really include enough details to make this a solutions someone could come up with. You said nginx was acting as a reverse proxy. That would mean that a header generated by the Apache server, which nginx is acting for as reverse proxy, would be passed on. With the setup you described the opposite setup, letting nginx deliver an additional header, would mean you'd see what is being delivered by it. Without details on your setup it's a valid assumption that nginx is acting as a proxy for any request to the Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by having Apache add an "X-Powered-By: Apache" header. This way, any requests being passed on to Apache would have the header, while requests handled internally by nginx would not.